# C# Stanford NLP online demo giving different output

Tags: c#, parsing, nlp

Using Stanford Core NLP 3.7.0 to create Dependency tree in C#. Same sentence giving different output in my application and the online Parser [demo](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp)

Sentence: Display Prime HomePage on page load.

**Online demo output:**

```
Universal dependencies

root(ROOT-0, Display-1)

compound(HomePage-3, Prime-2)
```

**dobj(Display-1, HomePage-3)**

```
case(load-6, on-4)

compound(load-6, page-5)

nmod(HomePage-3, load-6)
```

**My C# application output:**

```
Universal dependencies

compound(homepage-3, display-1)

 amod(homepage-3, prime-2)

 root(ROOT-0, homepage-3)

case(load-6, on-4)

 compound(load-6, page-5)

 nmod:on(homepage-3, load-6)
```

I am not getting the dobj which is available in Online demo output. Please advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the points i have noted, which may be helpful for others,

1. [Stanford CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process) and [Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp) are not providing similar output. It differs for the same input sentence.
2. Stanford CoreNLP - Case sensitive. Getting different output if the sentence case is modified.